# How to get all objectReferences in the current interior space

Tags: papyrus-script

I'm trying to get all objectReferences of all objects in the Skyrim room my character is in. How can I do this in Papyrus?

Answer (score 0):

Using SKSE you can get all Object References in a cell using [GetNumRefs()](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=GetNumRefs_-_Cell)
and, [GetNthRef()](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=GetNthRef_-_Cell)